# Scraping $nbsp with go

Tags: go, parsing, web-scraping, screen-scraping

While trying to learn Go and scrape a webpage I am running against a problem that I can't solve and find a good solution. I am trying to parse some values of the webpage and do it with a simple web scraping tool, here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/gocolly/colly/v2"
)

func main() {
    urlToScrap := "https://www.webpage.de/artikel/69443/index.html"

    collect := colly.NewCollector(colly.AllowedDomains("webpage.de", "www.webpage.de"))

    collect.OnHTML("div.tinyblock", func(h *colly.HTMLElement) {
        fmt.Println(h.Text)
        fmt.Println(strings.Repeat("=", 20))
    })

    collect.Visit(urlToScrap)

    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
}
```

but since the web page contains Non-breaking space ($nbsp), I can't get the value in the right div that I need, I am getting always  %%days_till%% tag and never the real value in it, how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you need to `%%some_words%%` is what in HTML, it's replaced by javascript on page load.

You might want to check `rec_template_replaces` in js of that page, and find the values you looking for.